# How to get Drop Down list option in Devkit Connector?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have requiremnet to provide drop down in custom Devkit connector. Can you please suggest option to provide drop down button ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum` in connector opertion parameter which will convert to drop down.